# build command-line-arguments: cannot load go-sql-driver/mysql

Tags: go, mysql-connector

I got an error

```
build command-line-arguments: cannot load go-sql-driver/mysql: malformed module path "go-sql-driver/mysql": missing dot in first path element
```

while application code is

```
package main

import "database/sql"
import _ "go-sql-driver/mysql"

func main() {
  db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:xxx@(127.0.0.1:3306)/dbname?parseTime=true")
  err := db.Ping()
}
```

I'v done with `go get -u github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql`, and `go.mod` was updated, it looks fine.

Can someone help to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Change the import to:

```
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
```

Go imports must have the full path to the imported module.